# Does Prometheus expose the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler's "Current CPU Utilization" as shown in the Kubernetes dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

In the Kubernetes dashboard, I can see for a HPA the following information:

```
Min Replicas:
3
Max Replicas:
11
Target CPU Utilization:
80%
Status
Current Replicas:
3
Desired Replicas:
3
Current CPU Utilization:
10%
Last Scaled:
5 days
```

However, I can't figure out how the 10% CPU utilization is calculated?

And if this value exposed via Prometheus?

Comment: 10% is calculated as 10% of the requested resources in the deployment.
So if you request 100mi, 10% is 10 milicores of CPU used.
As for prometheus, I have no idea.

Comment: And in the case of 3 replicas, do you know if this 10% is simply the average across the replicas?

Comment: Yes, average of all replicas

Comment: Did you ever find a way to get this in prometheus?  I have the prom operator, kube-state-metrics, but the actual percent doesn't seem to be exposed anywhere.  I would like to know the percent, not the desired/min/max/etc. replicas.

Answer (score 1):

As we can see from [kube-state-metrics/docs/horizontalpodautoscaler-metrics.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/1dfe6681e9/docs/horizontalpodautoscaler-metrics.md)

We just need to have kube-state-metrics along with HPA to start getting metrics in prometheus.